# The partial fraction expansion of $\frac{1}{x^n - 1}$.

Tags: special-functions, partial-fractions

If $n$ is an integer, is there a nice way to write the partial fraction expansion of $\frac{1}{x^n - 1}$? I figure that if $\zeta$ is the $n$-th root of unity, then for some coefficients $a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ we may write

$$
\frac1{x^n - 1} = \frac{a_0}{x - 1} + \frac{a_1}{x - \zeta} + \frac{a_2}{x - \zeta^2} + \ldots + \frac{a_{n-1}}{x - \zeta^{n-1}}.
$$

Then for $0 \leq i \leq n -1$,
$$
a_i = \lim_{x \to \zeta^i} \frac{x - \zeta^i}{x^n - 1} = \frac1{(\zeta^{i} - 1) \cdots (\zeta^i - \zeta^{i-1}) (\zeta^i - \zeta^{i + 1}) \cdots (\zeta^i - \zeta^{n-1})}.
$$
Is there a simpler expression for this and if so, how could I see it easily?

Comment: @bla: by the way, if you want to actually start from the expression you've got and turn it into what it should be, divide the denominator by (zeta^i)^{n-1} and note that the result is just the evaluation of the factorization of (x^n-1)/(x-1) at 1.  The real lesson to take away here is that since the LHS is invariant under multiplying x by zeta, the RHS must be also.

Comment: More generally, if a rational fraction $f(X)$ is defined at  a point $a$, then the polar part of $f(X)/(X-a)^n$ at $a$ is obtained by dividing the order $n-1$ Taylor approximation of $f(X)$ at $a$ by $(X-a)^n$. [The "polar part at $a$" is by definition the contribution of $a$ in the partial fraction decomposition.]

Comment: Continue to simplify the coefficient to
$$
a_i = \lim_{x \to \zeta^i} \frac{x - \zeta^i}{x^n - 1}=\lim_{x \to \zeta^i} \frac{1}{n x^{n-1}} 
= \frac{\zeta^i}{n}
$$

Answer (score 13):

Use l'Hopital's rule.  $a_i = \lim_{x \to \zeta^i} \frac{1}{nx^{n-1}} = \frac{\zeta^i}{n}$.  Note that the identity I am claiming is true is equivalent to the identity

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (\zeta^i)^k = \begin{cases} n \text{ if } n | k \\\ 0 \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

by taking the generating function of both sides.  More generally, the coefficient of $\frac{1}{x - a}$ in the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ is (as long as $a$ is a simple root of $Q$)

$$\lim_{x \to a} \frac{(x - a) P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{P(a)}{Q'(a)}.$$

This formula is tremendously useful (for example I recently used it on [this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/what-is-the-probability-of-a-coin-landing-tails-7-times-in-a-row-in-a-series-of-1/4675#4675)) but does not seem to be widely known.

Comment: Actually the 2nd formula is pretty well-known if you consider the limit is the residue of P(x)/Q(x) at a. (At least I find it on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Simple_poles) and a [UG textbook on Mathematics in Physics](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Methods-Physical-Sciences-Mary/dp/0471198269).)

Comment: So it is.  But back in my high school days when we were forced to do many partial fraction expansions I don't recall ever having come across it...

Comment: My sympathies on being subjected to "high school math", wherein there is an artificial need for "tasks" for students, which (perversely) argues against making things as easy as they can be. :)