# Geometrical significance of r.h.s. of set of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Express $[3, 14]$ as a linear combination of $[3, 4]$ and $[1, -2]$.

$\begin{bmatrix}
3&4\\
1&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\14\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
3&4\\
3&-6\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\42\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
3&4\\
0&-10\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\39\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
3&4\\
0&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\3.9\end{bmatrix}$

$\implies \begin{bmatrix}
3&0\\
0&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}18.6\\3.9\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
0&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}6.2\\3.9\end{bmatrix}$

Also, the values of $a,b$ are unique to the set of linear equations, so the solution means: $a = 6.2, b= -3.9$.

I want to extend this question to see the geometrical significance of the rhs.

So, the column vectors are: $v_1=a\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
1\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
18.6\\
6.2\\
\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2=b\begin{bmatrix}
4\\
-2\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-15.6\\
7.8\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

The original set of equations have two column vectors on left, and a r.h.s.

So, the r.h.s. of the original set of linear equations should have explicit representation in terms of $v_1, v_2$, as shown in the graphical representation [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvZI1.png). Seemingly, it forms the diagonal of the parallelogram formed by two vectors $v_1, v_2$.

But, is there an algebraic approach to show the same; as such an approach can help to prove easily the relationship.

[image]

---

***Edit:***

The parallelogram law of vector addition can be used here to check the same.

Here $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$, so the formula would lead to :
$v_3^2 = v_1^2 + v_2^2 - 2v_1.v_2.cos\theta,$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v_1$ and $v_2$.

It is found by taking sum of two angles- $\alpha, \beta$, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4xwO.png) (also, the [previous page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REsqL.png)); which are found as follows:

(i) $\alpha$: angle made by $v_1$ with positive -$x$ axis. 
It is given by $\tan^{-1}(\alpha) = \frac 13\implies \alpha = 18.41^o$.  
(ii) $\beta$: clockwise angle made by $v_2$ with negative -$x$ axis. 
 So, will ignore the negative value of the fraction $-0.5$. It is given by $\beta = \tan^{-1}(0.5)\implies \beta = 26.57^o$

So, $\theta= \alpha+\beta = 18.41^o+26.57^o = 44.98^o$.

So, putting the values in the parallelogram vector law, get:

$v_3^2 = v_1^2 + v_2^2 - 2v_1.v_2.cos(44.98^o)$

Need to get the two sides match

$205 = 384.4 + 304.2 - 2(19.606)(17.44)(0.707) $

$205 = 688.6 - 2(19.606)(17.44)(0.707) $

$205 = 688.6 - (19.606)(17.44)(1.414) $

$205 = 688.6 -  483.48$

$205 = 205.12$

---

***Edit 2*** This is in answer to the comment by @gen-zreadytoperish, which seems to imply that the vectors on the l.h.s. given should also be taken as column vectors rather than as row vectors. 
However, this is only possible when column vectors are taken from a system of equations with l.h.s. & r.h.s.  So, it is a notation or convention.

My approach (earlier) was based on taking individual vectors with each component defining a dimension. My approach can, unlike the latter approach, take vectors as representing a point in space; but as stated earlier it is notation to use the latter one.

By this modification, we get : 
$\begin{bmatrix}
3&1\\
4&-2\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\14\end{bmatrix}$

So,
$\begin{bmatrix}
3&1\\
2&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\7\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
3&1\\
5&0\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\10\end{bmatrix}\implies \begin{bmatrix}
15&5\\
15&0\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}15\\30\end{bmatrix}$$\implies \begin{bmatrix}
0&5\\
1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-15\\2\end{bmatrix} \implies a=2, 5b = -15\implies a=2, b = -3$

So, the column vectors are given by:

$v_1=a\begin{bmatrix}
3\\
4\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
6\\
8\\
\end{bmatrix}$, $v_2=b\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-2\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-3\\
6\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

The original set of equations have two column vectors on left, and a r.h.s.

So, the r.h.s. of the original set of linear equations should have explicit representation in terms of $v_1, v_2$, as shown in the graphical representation [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCMUj.png). It forms the diagonal of the parallelogram (shown in image as $v_3$) formed by two vectors $v_1$, $v_2$. 
[image]

Now need to prove by algebraic approach the relationship of the rhs vector as the diagonal of the parallelogram formed by $v_1, v_2$.

The parallelogram law of vector addition can be used here to check the same.

Here $v_3 = v_1 + v_2$, so the formula would lead to :
$v_3^2 = v_1^2 + v_2^2 - 2v_1.v_2.cos\theta,$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $v_1$ and $v_2$.

It is found by taking sum of two angles- $\alpha, \beta$, as shown above in Edit , found as follows:

(i) $\alpha$: angle made by $v_1$ with positive -$x$ axis. 
It is given by $\tan^{-1}(\alpha) = \frac 43\implies \alpha = 53.123^o$.  
(ii) $\beta$: clockwise angle made by $v_2$ with negative -$x$ axis. 
So, will ignore the negative value of $-2$. It is given by $\beta = \tan^{-1}(2)\implies \beta = 63.43^o$

So, $\theta= \alpha+\beta = 53.123^o+63.43^o = 116.53^o$.

So, putting the values in the parallelogram vector law, get:

$v_3^2 = v_1^2 + v_2^2 - 2v_1.v_2.cos(116.53^o)$

Need to get the two sides match

$205 = 100(=6^2+8^2) + 45(=(-3)^2+(6)^2) - 2(10)(6.708)(-0.447025) $

$205 = 145 + (8.94)(6.708) $

$205 = 145 + 59.969 $

$205 = 204.969 $

---

As each set of two linear equations has a unique set of values possible for $(a,b)$. So, there is only one solution possible for each set of linear equations, as two linear equations can only intersect at a unique point. As have taken up two different sets of two equations, so got two separate solutions. 
It can be seen that in both the set of two equations, the rhs vector : $v_3= \begin{bmatrix}3\\14\end{bmatrix}$ is forming diagonal of the two vectors $a.v_1, b.v_2$ in both cases, and satisfies the relation of $v_3 = a.v_1+b.v_2$.

---

***Edit 3:***

A useful site is: https://ximera.osu.edu/la/LinearAlgebra/VEC-M-0040/main.

Also, my first comment here is wrong in specifying the post (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1960990/424260); as the post supports the second approach. Confused how it happened.

Comment: Your matrix should be $\pmatrix{3&1\\4&-2}$. Expand what you have now and you’ll see that you have both $a$ and $b$ attached to the same vector. $6.2\pmatrix{3\\4}-3.9\pmatrix{1\\-2}=\pmatrix{14.7\\32.6}$

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Why should I do that, if am taking column vectors and computing as per that. Also, the $a$ is to be multiplied to the column vector comprising of the first component of each. You can check this calculation elsewhere here as https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1960990/424260 Hope that the given post will make it clear. I actually did not see that post before posting, and worked instead by seeing what is meaningful, and what works. Ditto for the Edit, but the book specified in Edit helped me in finding the algebraic relationship.

Comment: What do you mean, why should you do that? I just proved to you that your calculations of $a$ and $b$ are erroneous. If you want to actually find $a$ and $b$, then that’s why you should do what I’ve explained.

Comment: I have already told you what system to solve. There are many, many ways to solve a system in two variables, and I invite you to look them up on Google. Please take the hint that I do not want to answer the question as you have phrased it in your original post.

Comment: Also, to tell me that I “better [do something]” is ***quite rude***. It’s at worst half of a threat and at best shows a sense of entitlement on your part.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish Never meant like that, & have deleted it.

Comment: I recommend that you delete this question, take my advice and do some research on Google: look up “system of equations algebra.” If you still have a question then, ask a new one. What you have now is unattractively long and messy.

Comment: Your entitlement is astounding me. Do not continue to @ me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First regarding problem formulation:

You want to find $a$ and $b$ such that

$$a[3,4] + b[1,-2]=[3,14]$$

That is 
$$3a+b=3$$
$$4a-2b=14$$

We can write them in matrix form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\4 & -2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 14\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}$$

That is why you should put them in column rather than row.

Note that we have $$\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\4 & -2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix} 3 \\ 4\end{bmatrix} + b \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -2\end{bmatrix}$$

Alternatively, you can view them as $$\begin{bmatrix} a & b\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 4 \\ 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & 14 \end{bmatrix}$$

---

Now, regarding how to solve $(1)$, some of the ways include:

- perform Gaussian elimination
- solve the system of linear equations by substitution
- pre-multiply matrix inverse on both sides.

---

The solution is unique since the matrix is non-singular.

---

It seems that you are verifying the length of the vector by using cosine rule.

We indeed have 
$$205=100+45 -2(10)\cdot \sqrt{45}\cos(\arctan\left(\frac43\right)+ \arctan(2))$$

but as you round off numbers, you should be expecting that you are sacrificing some precision.

Note that $\beta = \tan^{-1}(2)$ and not $\tan^{-1}(-2)$ or you will get an obtuse angle.

Comment: I feel that the rhs of the alternative representation has typo. & should be $[3 \ 14]$.

Comment: Thanks,  I have corrected it.

Comment: Actually, will get an obtuse angle, but need the value of : $180^0 - $( that obtuse angle). Hence, I stated that need get the clockwise angle wrt the negative $x$ axis. So, your approach of ignoring the negative sign is effectively the same. Have edited my post too.

Comment: Please be in the last chatroom at : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105935/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten

Comment: Request clarification over taking column vectors, as per the modified approach (in Edit 2) (or, your approach) at last chatroom at (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108248/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten). I want to know if vector is here $2$-d, then how the two components are both of the same type. By geometry should have $2$ components. So, how it is possible to have both components of a vector to be of the same type. I mean first must be $x$-coordinate, second $y$-coordinate.

Comment: Please be in last chatroom for a query regarding  why book by Thomas Banchoff (titled: Linear algera through geometry, 2nd edn.) has taken vector (representing a single vector) as having $x$ coordinate as $(-b)$ for a line with equation $ax+by=0$; as at:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozqsu.png The book has till now taken vectors as points with $x$ coordinate first, & $y$ coordinate later.

Comment: The solution is stated (https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMbYi.png) at pg. 210 of the book titled Elementary algebra, 5th ed., by Tussy, Gustafson. Also, as per the book there should be two (equivalent) answers :  $\begin{pmatrix} -b\\a \end{pmatrix},  \begin{pmatrix} b\\-a \end{pmatrix}$. The slope of the line (of query) in my last comment is totally different however, as spans 1st & 3rd quadrants (positive slope: as $x$ part increases $y$ part increase, & vice-versa); rather than 2nd & 4th quadrants (negative slope).

Comment: Please be in the last chatroom (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108248/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten) regarding two different definitions of convex functions - (i) given in linear algebra texts, (ii) given in a book that uses the linear algebra based defn., but modifies that 'suddenly' to describe $-x^2$ as a concave fn.

Comment: Please be in the last chatroom, at : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108248/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten; for issue in understanding why $\{0,x,2x\}\ne \{0, x\}, x\ne 0$. As per me, both define a straight line; so both are convex.

Comment: Please be in the last chatroom for issue in understanding how angles are added at:  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2807050/424260

Comment: Please be in chatroom for a problem concerning finding y intercept of the line joining $1+i$and $−1$. Parametric form does not help, as does the slope-intercept form.

Comment: Please be in chatroom (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110379/new-room-108248) for a problem concerning parametric form of tetrahedron, as for Q.4  in image at: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJZvQ.png

Comment: Your response in chatroom was above my level, please elaborate.