Why is $i = (0,1)$?
My question concerns the construction of the complex numbers, why complex multiplication is the way it is, and why $i$ must be $(0,1)$. All the arguments I have seen tend to rely on the fact that we can represent each complex number uniquely as $a + bi$, which seems to assume that $i = (0,1)$, or they assume that we know the formula for complex multiplication already. I am wondering whether “$i = (0,1)$”, and the formula for complex multiplication, can be deduced.
Suppose the following: There exists a way to turn $\mathbb{R}^2$ into a field. Call this field $\mathbb{F}$, with addition and multiplication given by $+$ and $\times$, respectively.

The addition in $\mathbb{F}$ is the usual vector addition: $(a,b) + (c,d) = (a + c, b + d)$.

The multiplication in $\mathbb{F}$ is not yet known explicitly. (But since $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, the multiplication must obey all the usual laws like distributivity, associativity, etc.)

We require that $(a,b) \times (1,0) = (a,b)$ for all $(a,b)$. (This is reasonable: If $\mathbb{F}$ is to “extend” $\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{R}$ is thought of as lying on the $x$-axis, then the multiplicative identity should remain the same.)

There exists a number $i \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $i^2 = -1$. (This is reasonable: The whole point is that we want to have closure, to have roots even for negative numbers.)


From this, can we deduce that $i = (0,1)$? And that $\times$ is the usual complex multiplication? In short, is $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$?
Preferably, the deduction should come from elementary observations of the various algebraic properties of $\mathbb{F}$, instead of citing results like "$\mathbb{C}$ is the unique field extension of $\mathbb{R}$ that is 2-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$..." etc., unless necessary.
My attempt:
By the distributive and associative laws, $z(x + y) = zx + zy$ and $z(cx) = c(zx)$ for all complex $z, x, y$ and scalars $c$. This means that each complex number $z = (a,b)$ can be viewed as a linear transformation, mapping vectors of the plane to other vectors of the plane. Thus, we can think of $z$ as a $2 \times 2$ matrix. From the identity $ze_1 = z$, the first column of the matrix is $(a,b)$. But here is where I am stuck. Aren’t there infinitely many possibilities for the second column? That is, why can’t we allow $ze_2$ to take on a value other than $(-b,a)$?

No, there are other possibilities.  However, since they are all isomorphic, it is conventional to choose this particular one.

Cf. this question and this question and this lecture

Without pinning down more restrictions on the multiplication law, you could easily form a field where the addition law holds and $(1,0)$ is the multiplicative unit, but where $(1,1)^2 = (-1,0)$.

This answer may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3244132/what-is-a-simple-physical-situation-where-complex-numbers-emerge-naturally/3244234#3244234

Even if you knew $(a,b) \times (c,d)=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$ you would still have $i^2\equiv (-1,0) \implies i\equiv (0,1) \text{ or } i\equiv (0,-1)$ and would need to choose which.

@Henry This makes sense! After all, the polar form indicates rotation by angles counter-clockwise. But we could just as well have defined things clockwise.

You can take any $\mathbb{R}$-linear isomorphism $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the standard complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then define $(x,y)\cdot (x',y') := A^{-1}(A(x,y)\cdot A(x',y'))$. Then $A^{-1}1 = 1_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ and $A^{-1}i = i_{\mathbb{R}^2}$. For example $A= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $1_{\mathbb{R}^2} = (0,-1)$ and $i_{\mathbb{R}^2} = (1,1)$.

Great answer! Applying it to the specifics of my question, we see that even if $1_\mathbb{R^2}$ is required to be $(1,0)$, so that the first column of $A$ is $(1,0)$, there are still infinitely many possibilities for the second column of $A$ to make it invertible.

No, you can check that if we set $(0,1)=a+b*i$ with $b \neq 0,$ than all the properties you require are satisfied.
In fact this field is isomorphic  to $\mathbb{C}$ and it can be shown that up to isomorphism this is the only field structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that extends the field structure of $\mathbb{R}$ and respects the vector field structure.
This is because this field is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{R}-$ vector space and hence algebraic over $\mathbb{R}.$ And so over $\mathbb{C}$ as well. But $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed by the fundamental theorem of algebra, so the only possibilities are $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}.$ However it can't be $\mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{R}$ has no subfields isomorphic to itself.
The choice to visualize $i$ as $(0,1)$ is purely for convenience as it gives a nice geometric interpretation to multiplication as rotation plus scaling.
