Matrices $A, B \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb R)$ with $AB = A^2 + B^2$ and $\det AB = 0$
Assume that $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matrices with real-valued entries such that
$A^2 + B^2 = AB$ and $\det AB = 0$.
Is it possible to reveal any information about $n$, namely one of its divisors? I'd like a resource suggestion as a hint toward an answer rather than an actual answer, currently I'm not sure where to start.

Take $A=B$ to be a nilpotent matrix with $A^2=0$.

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/299651

For every $n$, you can find matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfying your conditions: just take $A$ and $B$ to be the zero matrix.
In other words, the fact that such matrices exist does not constrain $n$ at all.

Good point. What if we add a condition that $\det(BA - AB) \neq 0$?

@r0y Why are you adding that condition? Is there any context to motivate that? Because obviously you can add conditions to your question willy-nilly if all you want is to invalidate the answer you got for whatever reason. But I doubt if that will help you understand more about what you really want to know about.
