# Basic statistics

Tags: statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the probability of a coin landing tails 7 times in a row in a series of 150 coin flips?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/what-is-the-probability-of-a-coin-landing-tails-7-times-in-a-row-in-a-series-of-1)

I was wondering, if you flip a coin 100 times, what is the chance of getting 10 heads or 10 tails in a row? I think this could be a good way to respond to people who think that unlikely things don't happen by chance ( I suspect the chances are over 50%), but I don't know how to do the math.

Comment: When people invent a sequence of data, that fact  can often be detected from the paucity of runs. Also, if the data are to one decimal place, there will be a paucity of numbers ending in $.0$ and (to a lesser degree) $.5$.  But a true scientist would never never invent data. Never. Or at least would be smart enough to use a random number generator.

Comment: Probability of a run [1]http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511652