# If I flip a coin $n$ times, what is the expected maximum number of heads or tails in a row?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, expectation

**Question:** If I flip a coin $n$ times, what is the maximum number of heads or tails in a row that I should expect?

Comment: See [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4658/what-is-the-probability-of-a-coin-landing-tails-7-times-in-a-row-in-a-series-of)

Comment: As for the question of "flipping an infinite number of times," you seem to greatly misunderstand the meaning of infinity.  What will be true is that with a fair coin and an "infinite" number of coinflips, that any **finite-length** sequence of heads/tails will appear in the sequence, such as a billion heads in a row.  You cannot get an infinite string of heads however as that would contradict the notion that the coin is fair.  See [Normal Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).  Such a sequence of heads/tails could help us create a binary normal number.

Comment: @JMoravitz "grossly" is a bit strong

Comment: @JMoravitz: I cleaned up the question a bit as the part about an infinite number of flips does not seem well phrased.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an easy question.

Let $Z_0(n)$ be a random variable denoting the longest sequence of heads in a sequence of $n$ flips. In 1980, Guibas and Odlyzko showed that $$\mathbb{E}(Z_0(n)) = \log_2(n)+\frac{\gamma}{\log 2} -\frac{3}{2} +\rho_0(n)+o(1)$$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and $\rho_0(n)$ is an osscilatory function of $\log (n)$ bounded in absolute value by $1.6\cdot10^{-6}$. In particular, this leads to the surprising result that $$\mathbb{E}(Z_0(n))-\log_2(n)$$ does **not** have a limit. See this paper, [An Extreme Value Theory for Long Head Runs](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.81.4948&rep=rep1&type=pdf), by Gordon, Schilling, Waterman for more details.

Comment: Reading the linked article, I am surprised that the variance is as low as it is, being of the form $\frac{\pi^2}{6\log_2(n)}+\frac{1}{12}+\rho_0(n)+o(1)$.  Perhaps you can confirm what I'm thinking or missing from reading the article, with a fair coin, the expected longest sequence of heads tends towards the expected longest sequence of just heads *or* just tails, yes?

Comment: How can one prove $\mathbb{E}(Z_0(n)) = \log_2(n)+o(\log_2(n))$ elementarily ?