# Intersection hypercube with simplex

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Assume we have the hyperplane $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_N=S$ with $S\in R$ and $S>0$. Is there a formula giving/approximating the ratio between the area of the region satisfying the conditions: $0\leq x_i \leq M$ and that of the region satisfying $0\leq x_i \leq S$, where $S/N \leq M \leq S$?

I understand that we can see the region of the hyperplane $0\leq x_i \leq S$ as the simplex with N-1 dimensions, and that We can see the region I am looking for as as the intersection with a cube with a vertex in $O$ and edges $M$. I can solve the problem fixed $N$ ($N=2, 3$ is simple), but is there a general expression (even approximating) for this ratio for arbitrary $N$?

Comment: Just checking: Did you mean $S/N \leq M \leq S$?

Comment: Yes of course, sorry I was reasoning on the standard simplex on my own and hence I made the mistake

Comment: Not a complete answer, but if $M$ is sufficiently close to $S/N$ or to $S$, finding the volume amounts to calculating the volume of a simplex, possibly with truncated corners. This looks straightforward. For intermediate values, however, it looks as if there are complicated combinatorics. Offhand I don't know if formulas are known....