# Does the number of the same side appearing in a row converge to a finite number? Fair coin toss.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Toss a fair coin N times. Does the number of the same side appearing in a row converge to a finite number? If yes, what is it in terms of N? Are confidence intervals needed? Thank you!

Comment: i did not understand. can you please explain with an example?

Comment: This is not at all clear.  Please define precisely what you are trying to calculate.  If possible, give an example for $N=3$ say.

Comment: Okay! I meant the following. Let me do it with a greater N, say N=100. So when I toss the fair coin 100 times, what can I say about the longest HEADs in a row? That is With 95% confidence I can say that there will be no longer HEADs after each other than say 10. So the sequence would be: {H,T,T,T,H,H,T,H,WHATEVER,...,HHHHHHHHHH,T,...,LAST}

Comment: And so the larger N goes, there will be more likely to observe "long" rows of the same side, say HEAD. Example: N=100,000, there will be 15 HEADs in a row.

Comment: Because I was playing around with excel, and as I have increased N, the longest row of the same side was not increasing by the same factor as N did. Hence, I thought it might converge to a finite number. But then it is still a random process so confidence intervals might be useful to introduce to the picture.

Comment: [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials) is relevant.  As is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409372/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-largest-run-of-heads-if-we-make-1-000-flips)