# is it possible to find out how many times coin will return head in n-sequence?

Tags: probability

I would like to ask:

If we throw a coin 1000 times, expected result is we will get 500 heads from it, correct?

Now, is it possible to calculate how many times (max value) head will be selected in sequence within 1000 throws?

for an example in 1000 throws it is expected heead will fall in sequence of 10 within this 1000 throws.

We have number of throws = 1000
we have possible outcomes = 2
how many times will outcome be thrown in a row?

Thank you

Comment: The maximum value is 1000. It's quite unlikely, but happens with positive probability.

Comment: but what is the most likely?

Comment: You realize that's not what your question is asking, right?

Comment: I am just trying to figure out formula how to get most likely value...

Comment: @Testing man: It is unclear what you are asking here? Are you asking "what is the maximum length of consecutive heads that are likely (over 50% probability) to get from flipping 1,000 times? Or are you asking "what is the most likely maximum length of consecutive heads?"

Comment: Sorry for being unclear Owen. Yes it is the second.

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409372/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-largest-run-of-heads-if-we-make-1-000-flips (and pdf linked in the accepted answer). This shows that the maximum length of consecutive heads $L_n$ will satisfy $\frac{L_n}{\log_2 n}\to 1$ in probability (for $n$ total tosses).