# Expected value of the longest run of heads or tails in N flips of a coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

What is the expected value of the longest run of heads or tails observed in $N$ flips of a fair coin?

I'd like to consider this for any $N$, small or large.

Comment: Please write your problem specifically, instead of pasting links.

Comment: A very similar question with an accepted answer about the expected longest run of heads (instead of heads or tails): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409372

Comment: Thank you, I have had a look at that post, however, I am not sure how to generalise it to consider heads or tails.

Answer (score 1):

Following the approach suggested in [What is the expected length of the largest run of heads if we make 1,000 flips?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409372/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-largest-run-of-heads-if-we-make-1-000-flips), we expect $N_k=2n(1-p)p^k=n\left(\frac12\right)^k$ runs of heads or tails of length $\ge k$ (twice as many as if we only counted runs of heads). So a rough estimate of the expected maximum length is the solution for $k$ of $N_k=n\left(\frac12\right)^k=1$, which is $k=\log_2n$. Thus, the expected length is roughly the same as if we only count runs of heads, just $\log_22=1$ more.

[Here's code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/e6e951041297bc547bbeef3f4919b828) that simulates this difference. For $n=1000$, the difference is about $0.998$, in good agreement with the approximation. Thus, you can basically use the answers to the above question and add $1$.