# Finding the expected value of the longest substring of $1$'s

Tags: probability, expected-value

I need help with a question in my statistics book:

> Given a positive integer $n$. We want to form an $n$-bit string. Each bit is independently assigned as a $0$ or $1$ (each with probability $0.5$). Find the expected value of the longest sub-string of $1$'s.

I know how to calculate expected values however in this context I'm so confused that I have no idea how to even begin. How do we go about this?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this really an exercise in a stats book? It strikes me as a potentially difficult combinatorial counting problem. A suggestion: Compute the expected value for the first several values of $n$,  and look up the numerators (using $2^n$ as denominator) at https://oeis.org .

Comment: @BarryCipra yes it's a book exercise marked with a star, which indicates a "challenging exercise". Anyhow, let's say we want to compute the value for $n = 5$, how do we do it?

Comment: For small $n$ you can compute it by hand easily enough.  Just try it.

Comment: @lulu how do we do it for $n=1000$?

Comment: First try to compute it for small $n$, see if you see a pattern emerging.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409372/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-largest-run-of-heads-if-we-make-1-000-flips) is a duplicate and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59738/probability-for-the-length-of-the-longest-run-in-n-bernoulli-trials) is a generalization which allows for a bias towards $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @lulu I don't know if I'm doing this right, but like for $n=2$, the possible strings are $00, 01, 10,$ and $11$. So what is the expected value in this case? Using the formula $E(x) = \sum x \cdot p(x)$ I get 1/4.

Comment: For $n=2$:  The probability of getting a max of $1$ is $\frac 12$, the probability of getting a max of $2$ is $\frac 14$ so the answer is $0+\frac 12\times 1 +\frac 14\times 2=1$.

Comment: Note:  from the duplicates I linked to, you should see that there isn't a pleasant closed form for the general problem. The second link provides a full solution to the general problem, but it involves a rather gruesome sum.  But, as I said, it's easy enough for small $n$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much lulu, You've been really helpful.