# Expected longest run of consecutive heads or tails in $N$ tosses

Tags: expected-value

Suppose you toss a coin $N$ times. What is the expected longest run of consecutive heads or tails in $N$ tosses?

e.g., suppose $N = 5$. If the sequence is HHTTT, then the longest length here is 3.
If the sequence is HTHHT, then the longest length is 2.

I think this is a rather difficult problem. Is there a trick to get an answer easily for a generic $N$?

---

I attempted induction and failed. Here's what I tried.

Start with N = 1. The sequences are:

$$
H \\
T
$$

Where $L(1) = 1 \implies E[L(1)] = 1$ and $L(N)$ is the longest consecutive number of heads or tails among $n$ tosses.

Then we consider $N = 2$. Each time we have a branching factor of 2, where we can "tack" on a "H" or "T" to the sequences for $N = 1$, so we have
$$
HH \
HT \\
TH \\
TT
$$

Here the $E[L(2)] = 0.25 * 2 + 0.25 * 1 + 0.25 * 1 + 0.25 * 2 = 1.5$.

Now for $N = 3$, we have
$$
HHH \\
HHT \\
HTH \\
HTT \\
THH \\
THT \\
TTH \\
TTT
$$

Here, $E[L(3)] = 1/8(3 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 3) = 2$.
So based on this, I thought maybe we can induce $E[L(N)] = (N+1) / 2$.

but....for $N = 4$, we have
$$
HHHH \\
HHHT \\
HHTH \\
HHTT \\
HTHH \\
HTHT \\
HTTH \\
HTTT \\
THHH \\
THHT \\
THTH \\
THTT \\
TTHH \\
TTHT \\
TTTH \\
TTTT
$$

Here, $E[L(4)] = 1/16(4 + 3 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 4) = 2.375$

So $E[L(N)] = (N+1) / 2$ is not valid. So then I took a look at the realizations of $L(N)$, it appears that for each $N$, we have $2$ sequences with $L(N) = 1$ (obviously the alternating case) and $2$ sequences with $L(N) = N$ (obviously the all tails or all heads case). Then for $L(N) = 2$, it seems we have $2^{N - 1}$, and for $L(N) = 3$, we have $2^{N - 2}$.

e.g., for $n = 4$, when $L(N) = 3$, we have $2^{2}$ cases.

So in general, it seems we have that $L(N) = i$  with multiplicity $2^{N - i + 1}$ for $i = 2, \ldots, N$ and when $i = 1$, we have $L(N) = 2$.

So it seems we have
$$
E[L(N)] = \frac{1}{2^N}\left(2 +  \sum_{i=2}^{N} i 2^{N - i + 1} \right)
$$

But this formula breaks for $n = 5$...For example, $L(5) = 3$ has 10 distinct cases
$$
HHTTT \\ 
HTHHH \\ 
HTTTH \\ 
HHHTH \\ 
HHHTT \\ 
THHHT \\ 
THTTT \\ 
TTHHH \\ 
TTTHH \\ 
TTTHT \\ 
$$

At this point, I gave up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the expected length of the largest run of heads if we make 1,000 flips?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409372/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-largest-run-of-heads-if-we-make-1-000-flips)

Comment: @saulspatz I guess it somewhat partially answers my question even though that one is for the case of largest run of heads only whereas my case is heads or tails, but the gist that I got is "it's a difficult problem," and when I originally posted this, I was thinking perhaps there's an easy approach.

Comment: Yes, I see now that it is a different question, though I wonder if the answer is much different.  This [paper](https://www.csun.edu/~hcmth031/tspolr.pdf) appears to address the question you're interested in, under the heading, "Longest Run of Identical Outcomes", but I haven't read it.